# replace all img tag with anchor tag

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

Replace all img tag with anchor tag where img src attribute value should be anchor tag href attribute value. I couldn't get idea how to write pattern to match whole and replace img tag and return anchor tag with href value as src attribute value of img tag in following process function.

I have tried below:

```
$pattern = '/<img[^>]+>/i'; 
$callback_fn = 'process';   
$content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback_fn, $string);
function process($matches) 
{
        print_r($matches);
    return "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://mywebsite.com/".$matches[0]."'> <font color ='black' >View Image</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
}       
echo $content;
```

for example:

```
$string = "this is dummy string <img src="imageone.jpg" alt="" /> this is another sentesnces <img src="imagetwo.jpg" /> this is third one";
```

The output is:

```
this is dummy string View Image this is another sentesnces View Image this is third one
```

Here, View Image is link with

```
http://mywebsite.com/<img src="imageone.jpg" alt="" />
```

But I want this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/imageone.jpg
```

Comment: Don't do that manually, use better suited tools for your work: take a look at phps DOM extension. Otherwise you will get into hell with all the different coding options for an img tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$pattern = '/<img.+src=(.)(.*)\1[^>]*>/iU';
$callback_fn = 'process';
$string = 'this is dummy string <img src="imageone.jpg" alt="" /> this is another sentesnces <img src="imagetwo.jpg" /> this is third one';
$content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback_fn, $string);
function process($matches)
{
    return "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://mywebsite.com/".$matches[2]."'> <font color ='black' >View Image</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
}
echo $content;
```

Also instead of `<font>` tag, use `<span>` because `<font>` is deprecated.